# Makemigration throwing error

Tags: django, django-migrations

I am trying to rebuild my database, using makemigrations, Django 2.0. I've made some significant changes to my model: Deleted the `is_favorite` and `visit_specialty` which were both variables in the model that I deleted. 
I tried the usual `makemigrations`, `flush` / `sqlflush`, deleted the sqlite database file, and removed all migration files (not the **init**.py file).

Despite this, any "migration" command I input results in the below-mentioned error.

```
SystemCheckError: System check identified some issues:

ERRORS:
<class 'myapp.admin.VisitAdmin'>: (admin.E108) The value of 
'list_display[4]' refers to 'visit_specialty', which is not a callable, 
an attribute of 'VisitAdmin', or an attribute or method on 'myapp.Visit'.
<class 'myapp.admin.VisitAdmin'>: (admin.E108) The value of 
'list_display[5]' refers to 'is_favorite', which is not a callable, an 
attribute of 'VisitAdmin', or an attribute or method on 'myapp.Visit'.
```

Answer (score 1):

You still have them in your `admin.py` ( `myapp.admin.VisitAdmin`) and that is why you get following error

You have still both fields in `list_display`